How to keep admonitions in markdown -- pandoc --> docx convertion?
I have a Markdown source, cuirrently using admonitions in !!! TIP format (but I can eventually change this).
How do I keep admonitions, possibly with an icon, when converrting to docx format using pandoc ?

Pandoc does not support this by default.
However, Quarto, which is built on pandoc, supports this via callouts.
